Check the which is scheduled on a Task
So basically, I need to capture the batch configurations from Task scheduler. So whenever the User changes the batch configurations in a task scheduler for a specific batch. That needs to be monitored.

Is the question that you're trying to ask essentially this?: "Is there a way in C# code to read the configuration of tasks from the Windows Task Scheduler?  And is there a way to be notified when the Windows Task Scheduler is modified?"

yes. @David. exactly. Notified in the sense, I need a new configuration to be stored in table.

Install-Package TaskScheduler
using Microsoft.Win32.TaskScheduler;
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Replace with your task name
        string taskName = @"\YourTaskName";
        string connectionString = "your_connection_string";

        using (TaskService ts = new TaskService())
        {
            Task task = ts.GetTask(taskName);

            if (task != null)
            {
                // Get the task's next run time, trigger type, etc.
                TimeSpan interval = task.Definition.Triggers[0].Repetition.Interval;
                DateTime startBoundary = task.Definition.Triggers[0].StartBoundary;
                DateTime endBoundary = task.Definition.Triggers[0].EndBoundary;

                Console.WriteLine($"Task {taskName} runs every {interval} starting from {startBoundary} to {endBoundary}");

                // You can now compare this configuration with what's stored in the database
                // If changes are detected, update the database
                UpdateDatabase(connectionString, startBoundary, endBoundary, interval);
            }
        }
    }

    static void UpdateDatabase(string connectionString, DateTime startBoundary, DateTime endBoundary, TimeSpan interval)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            // Check and update your database accordingly
            string query = "UPDATE ClientTime_Duration_Configuration_Test SET clientStartTime = @start, clientEndTime = @end, modifiedDateTime = @modified WHERE ID = @id";

            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@start", startBoundary.ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@end", endBoundary.ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@modified", DateTime.Now);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", 1); // Assuming you're updating by ID

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
}


Polling Mechanism: Set up a loop to periodically check the task configuration:
while (true)
{
// Call the function to check task settings
CheckTaskConfiguration();
 // Wait for a specified time before checking again
 Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));

}


